# Why might links open in new window instead of a targeted iframe?

Tags: iframe, target

We have a menu opens that links in an iframe, as follows:

```
<a target='content' ...>

<iframe name='content' ...>
```

This worked correctly for most pages, but after opening one particular page and doing some work with it, all the menus began opening the content in a new window (tab). The link target was being ignored.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We traced the problem down to code like the following in one of the opened pages:

```
function x() {
    ...
    name = "y"
    ...
}
```

Because we had forgotten to enter the [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keyword, javascript was hoisting the variable called "name" to the global scope.

This overrode the name of the iframe, so the links could no longer find their target, and opened in a new window.

```
function x() {
    ...
    var name = "y"
    ...
}
```